# Collapsing toolbar leaves a white space when collapsed

Tags: android, android-layout

In my apps detailed activity I am using a collapsing toolbar to show the detailed activity with `ImageView` and `textView`'s. I don't want the toolbar to be collapsed so I am not using nested `scrollview`. And the appbar is also not transparent.

This is my current result[image]

And I want this result (only the above image and toolbar part)
[image]

and this is my xml layout 
`

< android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/grey_backgrouned"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="8">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/offer_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progress_bar_detailed"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_timer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_detailed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4.5"
        android:weightSum="4.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_scratch_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/drawable_dotted">

                <com.scratchkaro.consumer.scratch.WScratchView   xmlns:wsv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/scratch_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    wsv:antiAlias="true"
                    wsv:revealSize="20dp"
                    wsv:scratchable="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/scratch_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/star" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_scratch_offers"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:weightSum="5"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Address :" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shop_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="shop name"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address_line1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="address"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/city"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="city"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cell"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="cell"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_claim"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:text="Claim"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

`

And this is my `DetailedActivity` class:

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detailed);
    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_detailed);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
            (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
```

}

Comment: are you using a coordinator layout as root layout?

Comment: did you find the solution ? i'm having the same problem

Comment: yes i am using coordinator layout as root layout

Comment: no ii did not got the solution yet

Comment: try to delete: `app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"` and `
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"`

Comment: no its not working after deleting app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp" and  app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"`

Answer (score 0):

Top portion you see is android status bar. To hide it make sure your activity has full screen style. For example, you can set the below theme to your activity.

```
    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item></style>
```